# Default selections inside ng-repeat with ng-options drop down

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I can't figure out how to set default selections into Extras fields. 
Selection options are the same for both Main and Extras, but defaults should be set like following: [0] goes into Main and from [1] till the end of the list into Extras. Any advice on how to achieve that?

Structure is something like this:

```
 <div>Main selection</div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="mainInput" />
  <select data-ng-options="option.id as option.title for option in items" ng-model="mainSelection" ng-init="mainSelection = mainSelection"></select>

  <div>Extras</div>
  <div ng-repeat="i in extraSelections">
    <input type="text" ng-model="extraInput" />
    <select data-ng-options="option.id as option.title for option in items" ng-model="extraSelection"></select>
  </div>

 $scope.extraSelections = [];
  $scope.items = [{
      'id': 1,
      'title': 'Main/Extra'
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'title': 'Extra/Main1'
    },
    {
      'id': 3,
      'title': 'Extra/Main2'
    },
    {
      'id': 4,
      'title': 'Extra/Main3'
    }
  ];

  function getExtraSelections() {
    if ($scope.items) {
      for (var i = 1; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        var rowObj = {
          input: null,
          title: null
        };
        $scope.extraSelections.push(rowObj);
      }
    }
  }

  function setDefaultSelections() {
    $scope.mainSelection = $scope.items[0].id;
  }
```

Plunker:
    https://plnkr.co/edit/Yw94hLx3ntyOFL7AFmkx?p=preview

Edit: 
I've tried to use ng-init or ng-selected with passing model and index like this:

```
$scope.getDefExtra = function(model, index){
  model = $scope.items[index+1].id;
  return model;
}
```

The function gets and sets correct values, but there are no changes in view.

Answer (score 0):

Please change this

```
$scope.mainSelection = $scope.items[0];
```

to

```
$scope.mainSelection = $scope.items[0].id;
```

and `setDefaultSelections()` called after `$scope.items initialization`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did the edit with Main. But what about Extra selections? That's the main problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. 
The answer was simple:

```
 <select data-ng-options="option.id as option.title for option in items" ng-model="extraSelection" ng-init="extraSelection = setExtraDefault(extraSelection,$index)"></select>

$scope.setExtraDefault = function(model, index){
    model = $scope.items[index+1].id;
    return model;
  }
```